# JFileChooser component display weird

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to open a file in filechooser dialog, however, when i opened a file or simply close the dialog. The dialog appears again, i have to close it twice. Here is my code, don't know what's wrong with it

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ObjectInputStream input;
        JFileChooser openFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        openFileChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
        openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        openFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
        if (openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(openFileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
            input.close();
        }
        javax.swing.JFrame openFileFrame = new javax.swing.JFrame();        
        openFileFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        openFileFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        openFileFrame.add(openFileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        openFileFrame.pack();
        openFileFrame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code lines to create first one

```
JFileChooser openFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
openFileChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
openFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
if (openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
   input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(openFileChooser.getSelectedFile()));
   input.close();
}
```

and rest of code lines to embeding second one

```
javax.swing.JFrame openFileFrame = new javax.swing.JFrame();        
openFileFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
openFileFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
openFileFrame.add(openFileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
openFileFrame.pack();
openFileFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @Truong Thanh Dung you have to debug step by step code line by code line, no exception(s) when [I simulated FileInputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1260__JFileChooser.htm)

Comment: Tks mate, I got it rite finally, it is because I put exception handling with ObjectOutputStream then it display nullpointer when that variable is null :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first occurrence of openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

Comment: Well, each one of those calls creates the open file window. Also, shouldn't it be OPEN_DIALOG?

Comment: I got it fixed finally, tks so much mate :)